# Patterns to respond from the service layer

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am trying to list all the alternatives to communicate results back from the service layer to the presentation.

These results could be the actual return object(s) that I'm expecting from the service function, or exceptions.

I read about the Document Message and the Request-Response patterns, but they require me to create a class for every service function, and I would prefer to avoid that much coding.

I also read about hierarchical exceptions.

I am wondering if I am missing any other pattern to consider. Many thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I would prefer to avoid that much coding

Stop right there. That's what give you maintenance hell. Small well defined classes is easier to read and maintain.

If you use request/reply you'll get classes which focus on a single task.

An alternative is CQS (Command/query seperation) which have commands to execute stufF (they do not return any data) and queries to fetch data (no processing, just data retrieval).

The last option is service classes where each method correspond to one request or one command (or query). Service classes tend to get fat and people tend to not refactor the large methods to smaller as it's the difficult to tell which non-public method belongs to which public method.

Comment: @Bruno Not to mention that the request / response classes themselves create defined contracts of communication. They can contain useful things like report of success or failure, exception marshaling, and special case handling. In the long run you will benefit from this. Also a lot of the coding can be alleviated using T4 templates (or another code-gen mechanism).

Comment: I appreciate you both for sharing your experiences, thank you!